# cosets of $\langle1_3\rangle\times\langle 0_2\rangle\times \langle0_4\rangle\trianglelefteq\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Determine the left and right cosets of $H$ in $G$ and determine $(G:H)$.
>   $G=\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4, H=\langle1_3\rangle\times\langle 0_2\rangle\times \langle0_4\rangle$

I cannot find a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$, I only know in direct product how to compute the order of a cyclic group in which I know the generator(finding the order through  least common multiple). On this case I think $|\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4|=4\times3\times2=24$ and $ord(\langle1_3\rangle\times\langle 0_2\rangle\times \langle0_4\rangle)=3$
. So $(G:H)=\frac{|G|}{|H|}=\frac{24}{3}=8$

So we would have 8 right or left cosets.

However I do not know how to find the cosets.

**Question:**

How can I find the cosets(equivalence classes)? How can I write them down?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the subgroups $\langle 1_3 \rangle, \langle 0_2 \rangle, \langle 0_4 \rangle$ actually are? Not their order or anything else, but exactly what these three groups are.

Then can you figure out what the elements in their product are? They are not hard to list.

Now what does it say about two elements $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2) \in \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_4$ that there difference lies in $\langle 1_3 \rangle \times \langle 0_2 \rangle \times \langle 0_4 \rangle$?

After answering above, you should be able to list the cosets.

---

**Edit** to answer the question in the comment.

$\langle 1_3\rangle = \Bbb Z_3 = \{0_3, 1_3, 2_3\}\\\langle 0_2\rangle = \{0_2\} \subset \Bbb Z_2\\\langle 0_4\rangle = \{0_4\} \subset \Bbb Z_4$

So
$$\begin{align}\langle 1_3 \rangle \times \langle 0_2 \rangle \times \langle 0_4 \rangle &= \{0_3, 1_3, 2_3\}\times \{0_2\} \times \{0_4\} \\&= \{(0_3,0_2,0_4),(1_3,0_2,0_4),(2_3,0_2,0_4)\}  \end{align}$$

Comment: I think $\langle 1_3 \rangle\times \langle 0_2 \rangle\times \langle 0_4 \rangle$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3$, right? However I only found this equivalent class $\{(2_3,1_2,1_4),(1_3,1_2,1_4)\}$. I think only the first element can vary in this case $2_3$. However I am not seeing the other cosets and hoe they are going to be 8. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: $\langle 1_3\rangle = \Bbb Z^3, \langle 0\rangle = \{0\}$, so $$\langle 1_3 \rangle \times \langle 0_2 \rangle \times \langle 0_4 \rangle =\{(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0)\}$$. Now, what does it say about $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ if their difference is in $\langle 1_3 \rangle \times \langle 0_2 \rangle \times \langle 0_4 \rangle$? (By the way, your proffered equivalence class is missing a member.)

Comment: I cannot understand this equality $\langle 1_3 \rangle \times \langle 0_2 \rangle \times \langle 0_4 \rangle =\{(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0)\}$. What does it mean? How did you derive it? I am having a hard time understanding this exercise.

Comment: Could you provide me the solution please? That would help me out figuring out how I would solve this exercise.

Comment: I could not solve the question. Could you provide me an answer?

Comment: I added a demonstration that $\langle 1_3 \rangle \times \langle 0_2 \rangle \times \langle 0_4 \rangle =\{(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0)\}$ to the answer. You should note in particular that it has 3 elements, so any equivalence classes are also going to have 3 elements. But the set you gave as being an equivalence class has only 2 elements. And no, I am not going to just hand the answer to you so that you won't have to think about it. You have still to answer the question I keep asking you.

Comment: I tried to answer the question but I am having problems because there are lots of combinations. I know that $(x,y,z)\equiv(x´,y´,z´)\iff x=x´,y=y´,z=z´$ and $(x,y,z)\equiv(x´,y´,z´)\iff x-x´=1_3\vee x-x´=2_3,y=y´,z=z$. I found the equivalence classes $\{(1_3,1_2,1_4),(2_3,1_2,1_4)\}$ and $\{(2_3,1_3,1_4),(3_3,1_2,1_4)\}$. I think there are many combinations but I have computed $8$ on the initial post equivalent classes. Have I solved the problem?

Comment: I mean to complete my answer in of the previous comment. $\{(1_3,1_2,1_4),(2_3,1_2,1_4)\},\{(2_3,1_3,1_4),(3_3,1_2,1_4)\},\{(1_3,0_2,0_4),(2_3,0_2,0_4)\},\{(2_3,0_2,1_4),(3_3,0_2,0_4)\},\{(1_3,0_2,1_4),(2_3,0_2,1_4)\},\{(2_3,0_2,1_4),(3_3,0_2,1_4)\},\{(1_3,1_2,0_4),(2_3,1_2,0_4)\},\{(2_3,1_3,0_4),(3_3,1_2,0_4)\}$                                                                                                                                                                                                  I finally got the $8$ equivalence classes. Could you tell me if this answer is right?

Comment: No it is not right. As I mentioned in my last comment, every equivalence class will have $3$ elements, but all of yours only only contain 2 elements. $(x,y,z) \equiv (x',y',z')$ CANNOT be equivalent to two statements that are not equivalent to each other! In fact $$(x,y,z) \equiv (x',y',z') \iff y = y' \wedge z = z'$$The equivalence puts no restrictions on the value of $x$ at all. Note that $x$ can take on **three** values, not two.

Comment: In fact, I think now that you don't understand what an equivalence class is. Please review the definition. It is NOT just a set containing 2 equivalent elements. It is a set containing ALL elements that equivalent to anything in the set: $[\alpha] = \{\beta \mid \beta \equiv \alpha\}$. Thus any element cannot occur in more than one equivalence class, as EVERYTHING equivalent to it is already in that class. Also note that every element of $G$ is in an equivalence class. Yet your proffered classes only contain 12 of $G$'s 24 elements.

Comment: How should I write the equivalent classes then? I am not understanding what you are asking me. Can I define the equivalent classes in the following way: $(x,y,z)\equiv(x´,y´,z´), y=y´,z=z´$ and the $x$ varies?

Comment: In this case, you can list the elements in them, just as you did before (but with the right elements). And I think that would be helpful. When you are done, you will have 8 equivalence classes, each of which has 3 elements. All 24 elements of $G$ will occur EXACTLY ONCE as an element of those classes. Start with $(0,0,0)$ (I'm leaving the subscripts off as understood). What elements of $G$ are equivalent to it? (There are 3, including itself.) Those three elements form a class. Now choose any element of $G$ not in that class and ask the same about it. That gives the 2nd class. And so on.